# very strange Json need to be formatting

Tags: python, json

i got a json feed like this:

```
{'OUT': '232827@@@Price;1=9.8=0;2=4.1=1;3=7.9=0;#Needs;1=3.0=0;2=1.4=1;3=3.5=0;'}
```

it is very strange format:

1. Without KEYS
2. Used "=" to be separators
3. Two sets of data in one json array
4. With a prefix at the begginning(i am not sure the "OUT" isn't the prefix? maybe)

I want the output result like this with indicated Key:

**The First Json:**

```
{
  "No":1,
  "Price":9.8,
  "status":0
},
{
  "No":2,
  "Price":4.1,
  "status":1
},
{
  "No":3,
  "Price":7.9,
  "status":0
}
```

**The Second Json (After"#Needs"):**

```
{
  "No":1,
  "Needs":3.0,
  "status":0
},
{
  "No":2,
  "Needs":1.4,
  "status":1
},
{
  "No":3,
  "Needs":3.5,
  "status":0
}
```

Comment: Spoiler: it’s not JSON…

Comment: It is.... i can give you api privately

Comment: That string there is simply not JSON. It’s a string, which was maybe packaged in JSON at some point, but it itself is nowhere near JSON. It’s its own random, specific format.

Comment: 'https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/getJSON.aspx?type=winplaodds&date=2022-09-11&venue=ST&start=1&end=1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex will handle that nicely

```
import re

value = {'OUT': '232827@@@Price;1=9.8=0;2=4.1=1;3=7.9=0;#Needs;1=3.0=0;2=1.4=1;3=3.5=0;'}

result = []
for part in value['OUT'].split("Needs"):
    subresult = []
    for a, b, c in re.findall(r"(\d+)=([\d.]+)=(\d+)", part):
        subresult.append({
            "No": int(a),
            "Needs": float(b),
            "status": int(c)
        })
    result.append(subresult)

print(result)

[[{'No': 1, 'Needs': 9.8, 'status': 0}, {'No': 2, 'Needs': 4.1, 'status': 1}, {'No': 3, 'Needs': 7.9, 'status': 0}],
 [{'No': 1, 'Needs': 3.0, 'status': 0}, {'No': 2, 'Needs': 1.4, 'status': 1}, {'No': 3, 'Needs': 3.5, 'status': 0}]]
```

Comment: Wow! it works! Thank You Very Much! But how about the first Json? you just show the Second Json, Thanks again anyway , maybe i try myself later..

Comment: @KelvinYeung Look again, the result is a list containing 2 list, the first and second JSON. Or in the loop each `subresult` is one of you JSON

Comment: I tried but failed. I cannot split them into two  variables in list or dict format. I am sorry i am new for coding things (but i love it) could you please show me the further steps to make them clean? Thanks anyway..

Comment: @KelvinYeung `a = result[0]` and `b = result[1]`, these are the 2 list of dict

Comment: haha, such simple... Thanks !